# Setting and Accessing Global variables

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I need to have a set of `Global Variables` in a class, and need to access it from other classes. I have the following problems, can someone help me ?

1.) What type of class should i add ? is it a `View` ? Can someone show an example ?
2.) How can i set values to the variables in this class from my `Controller` and `View` classes ?
3.) How can i retrieve the values of these variables from this class (`global variable` class) ?

note: I know how to add it to the `app.js` and write/read from other classes. But i want to have a separate class for global variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add them as statics in a new class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.Utilities', {
    statics: {
        myGlobal: 1
    }
});
```

At which point you load the class up and from anywhere in the app you can write `MyApp.util.Utilities.myGlobal = 5`.

This is an extension of my answer here to a similar problem: 
[Where should I define global functions in ExtJS 4 MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261458/where-should-i-define-global-functions-in-extjs-4-mvc/9277950#9277950)

Comment: Thankyou, so i should Add it in `/MyApp/util/` folder ? If i am using Sencha Architect IDE how am i going to add this file in the said location ?

Comment: Yes, but feel free to name it anything you like and put it in the corresponding location. I've never used Architect so I can't help with that, sorry.

Comment: How do i `load the class up` ? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Simply require it in any class that uses the globals. See the linked answer above for an example.