# ExtJS4: Accessing global variables from Ext.Application

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to load some application specific settings and save them as global variables when the application is loaded. I have found how to create and access global variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615277/setting-and-accessing-global-variables).

This is how my `app.js` looks like:

```
Ext.application({
    stores: [
        ...
    ],
    views: [
        ...
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    name: 'MyApp',
    controllers: [
        'DefaultController'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Is it possible to set these variables inside `launch: function()` block? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also create a singleton:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.Utilities', {
     singleton: true,

     myGlobal: 1
});
```

in your app:

```
Ext.application({
    stores: [
        ...
    ],
    views: [
        ...
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    name: 'MyApp',
    controllers: [
        'DefaultController'
    ],

    requires: ['MyApp.util.Utilities'], //Don't forget to require your class

    launch: function() {
        MyApp.util.Utilities.myGlobal = 2; //variables in singleton are auto static.
    }
});
```

Comment: I just found that out and you posted it on time :) 
Additionally it works without `singleton` too. Thank!

Comment: Yeah, but if you `Ext.ceate()` a class with `singleton: true` you won't have a new instance, so it's safer to use it.

Comment: Why can't I access myGlobal in a store?