# ExtJS 4.2 Accessing Array Elements returned from store

Tags: arrays, store, extjs4.2

I am unable to access the store elements returned from my store.  When I console.log(me.proxy.read(operation)) and expand/navigate in the console I see all of my elements.  There are 1000 rows.  I am using the same store for a grid and have the pageSize set to 50.  Even though I can see 1000 rows when i do a console.log(me.proxy.read(operation.resultSet.records[51])) i get an undefined message.  So, it appears that for some reason the number of elements I can access is only 50 as that is what my pageSize is set to.

Long story short, I am using the same store for two scenarios.  I want to have paging in my grid that will show 50 rows on each page.  However, I want to loop through the entire store and load an array of all 1000 rows.  The reason why I want an array of all 1000 is becasue I am going to use a date field in the rows to populate my date picker from an array.  I am going to disable the dates in my grid and have the datepicker display only the dates that are in my grid.

I tried to include a screen shot but I am not allowed because i am only a 3 on the reputation system.

```
var operation = new Ext.data.Operation({action: 'read', start: 0, limit: 1000});
var proxy = new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({ url: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2.cfc?method=getContent'});
me.proxy.read(operation);
console.log(me.proxy.read(operation));
```

HERE IS UPDATED CODE:

```
I have this in my controller:                                              

ondatesStoreLoad: function(me,records,success)
{
var s = this.getStore('dates');
    for (i = 0; i < s.getCount(); i++) {     
        MESSAGE_ID = s.getAt(i).get('message_id');
        RECIP_EMAIL = s.getAt(i).get('recip_email');
        UNIX_TIME_STAMP = s.getAt(i).get('unix_time_stamp')
        console.log(i,MESSAGE_ID, RECIP_EMAIL, UNIX_TIME_STAMP);
    };}
```

This puts out all 1,000 of my records to the console but I am not sure how to put them in an array that I can use in my datepicker component.  When ever i try to get the store in the datepicker it is always undefined.  I suppose it is becasue the store hasn't loaded yet so there is nothing there.  Not sure how to get around that.  Perhaps a callback handler?

HERE IS ANOTHER UPDATE:

I added a callback in my store.load:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('dates');

store.load({callback: function(){
    console.log(store.data.items[999].data.recip_email);
    console.log(store.data.items[999].data.unix_time_stamp);}
})
```

That took forever to figure out but now I can access all my records and have a smaller problem to work on.  At the moment i just have one element hardcoded to do a quick test.

Where do I need to put the code to get it into my date picker disableDates config? I need to put the dates into an array but for quick testing I used minDate: just to see if i could see something work but it shows up as undefined.  Now i have the code in a beforrender listener but that seemingly needs to be in some other place or maybe some handler for my date picker....? is there an onload for the datepicker or something i shoudl use for this??

Comment: As far as I know, when using a paged grid, only the currently displayed set of records are loaded. So in your case, only 50 at a time. You could do a separate server call, that doesn't use your store, to retrieve the 1000 records to update the date picker.

Comment: Also, why are you manually creating an operation? If you create a store with a proxy in it, you just call `.load()` on the store to load the data. No need to do an explicit `.proxy.read()` call.

Comment: ** Disclaimer: I am struggling with this frame work. While I have a grid setup to pull from my server and some other basic stuff, it has been painful. Long story shorter is that I don't know what I am doing.  With that, I just found some code snipets to try for accessing the store out of desparation and had some success with being able to see all 1,000 records so I kept trying to use that to get something working.  My intention was to try and get everything i can from the store before making another trip to the server.  Should  i not worry so much about that?

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest making good use of the ExtJS docs. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store There is the link to the `Store`. Also, they have tons of working examples here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example These examples come with code that you can view, so you can see what they did.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help but like everyone else I see posting on this forum it seems like my opinion on the docs are shared with everyone else.  There is not one example that can be applied to the MVC pattern they give as example.  I am not able to make the jump.  It is poor.

Comment: Let me expand..... they don't give examples of how it all fits together for a perferered method of implementation.  Is all data access made through store? should it be? if you need to load an array for datepicker do you use operation config to do it? like i say, there is no answers on that kind of a use case.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I can tell you what I do. If I'm loading remote data into a grid, I almost always set up a remote store that loads the data automatically. If I'm doing anything manually with the data, I usually make an explicit call to the server to retrieve the data once. In your case, it might be easier to just explicitly retrieve all the data so you can update the date picker, and then use the store you currently have for the grid, so it handles the paging correctly.

Comment: That is what seemed to emerge from all the chaos i have been reading through on the net and is what I was attempting to do.  My road block is once i make the call and get the data i cannot figure out how to access it.  I want to load it in an array.  I can see in console the records are there but no matter what i do i cannot grab them an stick them in an array.  I managed to figure out where to put a listener for store load.  How do you typically make the call? like this? var store = Ext.getStore('dates');

Comment: `Ext.getStores()` simply returns a store you have created, it doesn't make the server call. If you have a store configured, you can call `.load()` on the store, and that will retrieve the data. I use DWR for all my server calls, not explicit ajax, so I can't help you with the specifics on that. However, it sounds like you could set up two stores, one paged one for the grid, and one that loads all the data. I don't think that's the best solution, but it could work.

Comment: I added code to my post above to look at.  How do I get this in an array that will persist accross my components? I can only get this array data from the load load listener in my controller.

Comment: I said the 'F' word 93 times.  I am getting closer.  In my original post I made another update to look at.  Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just change the datepicker directly from that `ondatesStoreLoad` function? Before the loop, disable all dates in the datepicker. Then during the loop, instead of the `console.log` call, enable the date that was found in that record.

In theory, that should work. However, looking at the docs for Ext, I don't see a way to disable all dates, or to enable a date. You can only set which dates are disabled. But the general idea of updating the datepicker in that `ondatesStoreLoad` call is still what you should do.

You might need to extend the datepicker class, and add some custom methods to it to be able to enable a specific day.

Comment: I think I have the date part figured out.  Since the disable dates is evaluating using regular expression then all I need to do is invert it then it gives the dates that are not in my list.  I tried that on a hard coded array and it worked. The othere part of your comment sounds like a winner. I am going to give it a shot and post back what I find. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Okay, cool, then just stuff all the dates into an array instead of calling `console.log`, and then use that array in place of your hard coded one.

Comment: Yeah, I found the disable date solution on this site some where.  Can't remember where but if you search it comes up near the top I think

Comment: I try to set my variable in the handler fucntion ondatesStoreLoad but it is showing undefined.  The only place I can set the variable where i can get it is in the init:function() where I add my store listeners.  If i set the global variable there I can set my datepicker minDate with it.  Otherwise no such luck.  Where does someone who knows what they are doing set this?? I googled but I don't see exact example on how to set vars in EXT MVC.  Really confused becasue things that seem simple to me are anything but so I am missing the fundamentals - clearly.

Comment: Is this proper?                                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184981/extjs4-accessing-global-variables-from-ext-application

Comment: Looks like the poster is defining a class and setting configs.  Then requires it in application file and sets value in the launch function.  This seems like a clean way to do it but is it preferred method most folks use?

Comment: I suggest you do some research on scope of variables in javascript. Ext is a javascript framework, so it follows the same scope rules for variables.

Comment: I did, it didn't help.  I feel like i have thourhouly tried just about everything I could think of.  It is not like other languages I am accustomed to like c++ or scripting like CF ect.... Totally lost here.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct for the premise of where to load my array.  Here is a post that gave me correct answer for date picker. It had nothing to do with scope but more to do with querying the DOM.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925610/extjs-4-2-dynamically-load-date-picker-value-newbie-q                         the final working code is in the link above.  Thanks for you helping me on this forgivenson.