# ExtJS 4.2 - Dynamically Load Date Picker Value - Newbie Q

Tags: variables, datepicker, extjs4.2

The ExtJS Frame work does not give obvious way to use variables.  I am trying to dynamically load the datepicker with an array for disabledDates:.  I have tried a bunch of different ways but it always come down to the fact that any variable I try to access is undefined.  What is the perfered method for dynamically loading the configs for datepicker? What is the perfered method to use variables between controller and components?

I have the array loaded in my controller.  How do I use it to set values on my date picker configs? At the moment I am hardcoding some dates in dateArray and it is working.  I want to load this dynamically.

***Controller:***

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores:['Users', 'dates'],
models:['User', 'date'],
views: ['user.List','user.Edit'],


init: function() {

Ext.getStore('dates').addListener('load',this.ondatesStoreLoad, this);


this.control(
   {


    'viewport > userlist':
    {
        itemdblclick: this.editUser,
    },


    'useredit button[action=save]':
    {
        click: this.updateUser
    }           



});

},


// ----------  handler Function declarations  -------------

ondatesStoreLoad: function(me,records,success)
{


// ------  Gets the dates from dates store and loads an array
var store = this.getStore('dates');
sendDataArray = [];

store.each(function(record){
var recordArray = [record.get("unix_time_stamp")];
sendDataArray.push(recordArray);
});         

// ------  Gets the dates from dates store and loads an array

},


editUser: function(grid, record)
{
var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
view.down('form').loadRecord(record);

},

updateUser: function(button)
{
var win    = button.up('window'),
    form   = win.down('form'),
    record = form.getRecord(),
    values = form.getValues();


record.set(values);
win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
}   
});
```

***ViewPort:***

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

// This array is for testing.
dateArray = ["01/01/2014","01/06/2014","01/08/2014","01/20/2014"];


Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'AM',
appFolder: 'app',
controllers: ['Users'],

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

    layout: 'border',

     items:
        [{

            region: 'center',
        title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
            activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default

                items:
            [{xtype: 'userlist'}]
            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',

            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
                height: 100,
                minHeight: 100,
            items:
            [{
                title: 'Tab 1',
                xtype:'panel',

                items:
                    [{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    minDate: new Date('01/02/2014'),
                    maxDate: new Date(),
                    disabledDates:["^("+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],
            }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

***UPDATED CONTROLLER:***

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores:['Users', 'dates'],
models:['User', 'date'],
views: ['user.List','user.Edit'],


init: function() {

Ext.getStore('dates').addListener('load',this.ondatesStoreLoad, this);

    this.control(
    {

        'viewport > userlist':
        {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser,
        },

        'useredit button[action=save]':
        {
            click: this.updateUser
        }           

    });

},


// ----------  handler Function declarations  -------------

ondatesStoreLoad: function(me,records,success)
{

// ------  Gets the dates from dates store and loads an array
var store = this.getStore('dates');
sendDataArray = [];

store.each(function(record){
    var recordArray = [record.get("unix_time_stamp")];
    sendDataArray.push(recordArray);
});         


// ------  Set DatePicker here  --------//

var dtFld = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#datePickerFld')[0];

dtFld.setDisabledDates(["^(?!"+sendDataArray.join("|")+").*$"]);
dtFld.setMaxDate(new Date());
dtFld.setMinDate(new Date('05/01/2013'));

},

editUser: function(grid, record)
{
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

updateUser: function(button)
{
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
},

});
```

***UPDATED VIEWPORT:***

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'AM',
appFolder: 'app',
controllers: ['Users'],

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items:[{
            region: 'center',
            title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 0,
            items:[{
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                    listeners:
                    {
                        select: function(selModel, record, index, options)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('select');
                        },
                        add: function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('add - init2.js');
                        },
                        afterrender:function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('afterrender - userlist(init2.js)');
                        },
                        beforerender:function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('beforerender - userlist(init2.js)');
                        }
                    }
                  }]
            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',
            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
            height: 100,
            minHeight: 100,
            items:[{
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    xtype:'panel',
                    items:
                        [{
                        xtype: 'datepicker',
                        itemId:'datePickerFld',
                        listeners:{
                            beforerender: function(){
                                console.log('datepicker - beforerender(init2.js)');
                                var store = Ext.getStore('dates');
                                store.load({callback: function(){
                                console.log('datepicker - callback(init2.js');
                                console.log(store.data.items[999].data.recip_email);
                                console.log(store.data.items[999].data.unix_time_stamp);
                                }
                                })
                            }
                        },

                        handler: function(picker, date)
                            {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('date picker example in init2.js' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            // get store by unique storeId
                            var store = Ext.getStore('Users');

                            // clear current filters
                             store.clearFilter(true);

                            // filter store
                              Ext.encode(store.filter("unix_time_stamp", Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y')));

                            store.load();
                            store.sync();
                            }
                        }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'ers may be added dynamically  - Others may be added dynamically',
            }]

         }]
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `datepicker` method [`setDisabledDates()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-setDisabledDates) which accepts a string array of dates.  If you are getting the dates dynamically from a store load, then you will want to query for your component and execute the method within the store load as well.

You can add an `itemId` to the specified datepicker to make it easier to query.

```
            [{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    minDate: new Date('01/02/2014'),
                    maxDate: new Date(),
                    disabledDates:["^("+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],
                    itemId:'datePickerFld'
            }]
```

Then query within your store load and set the disabled dates...

```
var dtFld = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#datePickerFld')[0];
dtFld.setDisabledDates(disabledDatesArray);
```

Comment: Cant thank you enough... I made the changes you suggested and tested. It worked so started to clean up my code. I was suprised to see other stuff start working (like my filter) just by cleaning up what i had.  I didn't even realize it wasn't working unil i saw it behave different.  Just goes to show how much time I would have wasted and continued to waste with out your help.  One last question. My date picker loads all dates, then it disables the correct dates.  Anyway to make it not show the date picker until the disabled dates are initialized? Actaully it is loading all components one by one

Comment: I added my updated code.  It shows some other things I have stubbed in as place holders for where my listeners & handlers show logging during my learning curve.  Anyrate, It is the same code it justlooks a little different from my initial post.

Comment: There are a couple options there depending on the ui experience you are looking for.One option,  You could default these components to [disabled](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-disabled) in config and then [enable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-enable) once the data is loaded in the store load event.

Comment: In my UPDATED VIEWPORT above would I disable the tabpanel in each region? Then, do the same and add itemId for both tabpanels so I enable them the same as my datepicker disableDates i presume?

Comment: If i do disable it is greyed out and as you would expect disabled.  Is there a way to not show anything until everything is loaded? This is the ui experience you refer too?

Comment: Actually, i can still see that the dates initially load with the disabled itme set to true as well.

Comment: The other option is to make the component [hidden](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-hidden) and then [show](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-show) the component when loaded.  Note, these configs & methods are available on any component inheriting from `Ext.Component` so they'll work on `tabpanel` too.

Comment: OKay, thanks a bunch.  I think the last suggestion you made looks nice for now.  I am new to SO.  Should I up vote your or something for this extra help? Hate to sound like a dummy but I have no choice in the matter ;-)

Comment: You can upvote answers if you think they are useful (you can also upvote other answers to questions if you didn't ask them too) however, it isn't a requirement.  Totally up to you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is SO document on it. :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to up vote yet.  I will have to circle back on that one. Thanks!