# Where should I define global functions in ExtJS 5 MVVM? 1

Tags: extjs5, utilities

I need to create/call a specific class to have utilities functions for my app. 
This exactly correspond to this topic: 
[Where should I define global functions in ExtJS 4 MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261458/where-should-i-define-global-functions-in-extjs-4-mvc)

But this, do not work with ExtJS 5. So I would like to know how make with ExtJS 5.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean "do not work"?

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton class with all these functions, give the class an alternate name like Utils. Require the class in the main application and simply use Utils.method